# Suppose $a, b, c \in I$ such that greatest common divisor of $x^2 + ax + b$ and $x^2 + bx + c$ is $(x + 1)$ and the least common multiple...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, polynomials, factoring

> Suppose $a, b, c \in I$ such that greatest common divisor of $x^2 + ax + b$ and $x^2 + bx + c$ is $(x + 1)$ and the least common multiple of $x^2 + ax + b$ and $x^2 + bx + c$ is $(x^3 - 4x^2 + x + 6)$. Find the value of $|a + b + c|$.

My attempt : 
$$x^2 + ax + b = (x + 1)Y$$
$$x^2 + bx + c = (x + 1)Z$$

From here onwards I do not how to continue. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: From the first part, for $x + 1$ to be a common divisor means that $f\left(x\right) = x^2 + ax + b$ and $g\left(x\right) = x^2 + bx + c$ must both be $0$ at $x = -1$. Thus, we get that $f\left(-1\right) = 1 - a + b = 0$ and $g\left(-1\right) = 1 - b + c = 0$.

Comment: Can someone please help me solve fully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $x^2+ax+b$ and $x^2+bx+c$ have the same factor $x+1$.

But $$x^3-4x^2+x+6=x^3+x^2-5x^2-5x+6x+6=$$
$$=(x+1)(x^2-5x+6)=(x+1)(x-2)(x-3),$$ which gives that our polynomials they are:
$$(x+1)(x-2)=x^2-x-2$$ and $$(x+1)(x-3)=x^2-2x-3.$$
 Id est, $b=-2$, $a=-1$, $c=-3$ and
$$|a+b+c|=6.$$

Answer (score 1):

Using GCD $\times$ LCM = Product, we get
$$(x+1)(x^3 - 4x^2 + x + 6) = (x^2+ax+b)(x^2+bx+c)$$
Now it remains to equate coefficients on both sides to get $(a, b, c) = (-1, -2, -3)$